# C# Referenced Component can't be found

Tags: c#, reference

I'm trying to set up a svn Project with Visual Studios. But I have a problem with the references. Some references are said to be missing. I tried to start a new Project on my computer and the refrence which are missing in the svn are automatically in the local project.

I tried to add the missing references to my project but I can't seem to find them. I have included a picture how my references look like at the moment. On the left side is the svn project and on the right it's my local one.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help
Fabio

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed these: http://www.antlr.org/download.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DotNetOpenAuth assemblies framework version and your project framework destination. When you are importing non compatibles assemblies they are added to the project but It can't find namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but I'm not sure what I need to do now. I checked the framework version but my refrences which are not found have a Version 0.0.0.0. Could you explain a bit more what you mean with the framework destination. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We just found a solution why it didn't work. The problem was the ankhSVN was causing problems. So we just got rid of it and kept tortoise. Thank you for your time :D